# Calling modules from Python dir()

Tags: python

**Short Question**
Is it possible to call a module as retrieved from the python dir() function?

**Background**
I am working on building a custom test runner and would like be able to choose which modules to run based on a string filter.  See my examples below for ideal usage.

**module_a.py**

```
def not_mykey_dont_do_this():
    print 'I better not do this'

def mykey_do_something():
    print 'Doing something!'

def mykey_do_somethingelse():
    print 'Doing something else!'
```

**module_b.py**

```
import module_a
list_from_a = dir(module_a) # ['not_mykey_dont_do_this', 'mykey_do_something', 'mykey_do_somethingelse']

for mod in list_from_a:
    if(mod.startswith('mykey_'):
        # Run the module
        module_a.mod() # Note that this will *not* work because 'mod' is a string
```

**Output**

```
Doing something!
Doing something else!
```

Comment: [testoob](http://code.google.com/p/testoob/) allows you to select tests using regex. You can see how they do it, or just use the whole framework if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
getattr(module_a, mod)()
```

getattr is a builtin function that takes and object and a string, and returns the attribute.

Comment: Awesome.  I wish I would have looked a bit closer in the built in functions.

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

```
import module_a
list_from_a = dir(module_a)

for mod in list_from_a:
    if(mod.startswith('mykey_'):
        f = getattr(module_a, mod)
        f()
```